# Sol Lagrange points

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics

Where are the Sol-Sagittarius A* Lagrange points, what is located there, have we ever focused a telescope to look? And the larger question, could the existence of these points offer some explanation for the structure of the galaxy's arms?  For example, is Sol located at the Lagrange point of another Star in the galaxy?

Comment: The *useful* existence of Lagrange points hinges on a low-perturbation assumption which surely not reasonable in the galactic context.

Comment: The sun is not really affected by the gravitational force of Sgr A* (similarly for most objects in the galaxy), so I don't see how Lagrange points could be derived for Sun+Sgr A* system.

Answer (score 3):

The [Lagrange points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) are only well defined for a two body system. The Earth-Sun Lagrange points exist only because the perturbations caused by the Moon and the other planets are relatively small.

By contrast there are lots and lots of stars and dark matter between the Earth and Sgr A*, so this isn't even remotely a two body system. The mass of Sgr A* is something like 4 millions Suns, but the mass of the whole Milky Way is about a trillion Suns. Exactly how much of that mass lies between us and Sgr A* is a somewhat involved calculation, but the mass of other "stuff" between us and Sgr A* is likely to outweigh Sgr A* by several orders of magnitude.

So there is no singnificant gravitational interaction between the Earth and Sgr A*, and therefore no Lagrange points. The Earth orbits in the gravitational field of all the matter in the Milky Way, not in the gravitational field of Sgr A*.